# pygis zoom to selected layer

Tags: qgis-plugins, zoom, ppygis

I selected the layer I want to zoom in and I can actually zoom in using the python console that Qgis provides using

> iface.zoomToActiveLayer()

but if I do the same in my code, is like that line is being ignored.

code here:

```
def openFileNameDialog(self):

    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Shapefile's (*.shp)", options=options)
    if fileName:
        shape_name = fileName

    shapelayer = QgsVectorLayer(fileName, "project's shapefile", "ogr")
    if not shapelayer:
      self.statusBar().showMessage('shapefile is invalid')

    else:

        urlWithParams = 'url.to.map'

        rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'BaseMap', 'wms')

        if not rlayer.isValid():
            self.statusBar().showMessage('Layer failed to load!')

        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(shapelayer)

        self.iface.setActiveLayer(shapelayer)

        #self.boxlayer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        #self.canvastry = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        #extent = self.boxlayer.extent()
        #self.canvastry.setExtent(extent)
        #self.box = self.boxlayer.boundingBoxOfSelected()
        #self.iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(self.box)
        #self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

        self.iface.zoomToActiveLayer()
```

commented lines between setActiveLayer() and zoomToActiveLayer() are other tries i've done and haven't worked from what I've read in the forums.

EDIT:

I've realized that iface.zoomToActiveLayer() is working but it's also being called before layers are loaded into Qgis and that's the bug preventing that line to execute correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling the

> iface.zoomToActiveLayer()

is the correct method to use, so calling the line after the layers are loaded would solve the problem.

Using render signals it can be automatically zoomed in